# Refresh div by class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have table render with PHP using foreach loop.

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $comment->lot_date }}
                        <br>
                        @if (count($comment->ourcar) >= 1)
                            <p>Saved</p>
                        @else
                            <form method="POST" action="/comments/{{ $comment->id }}/ourcars">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Our Car</button>
                            </form>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('comments.show', $comment->id) }}">{{ $comment->bid }}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->auction_name }}</td>
                    <td class="block">
                        @foreach(explode('#', $comment->pics_urls, 3) as $pic)
                            <a href="{{ $pic }}" class='iframe'>
                                <img src="{{ $pic }}" class="img-fluid" width="30" height="32">
                            </a>
                        @endforeach
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->company }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->model_name_en }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->model_type_en }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->grade_en }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->model_year_en }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->color_en}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->displacement }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->transmission_en }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->scores_en }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->mileage_num }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->start_price_en }}</td>
                    <td><div class="comment-body">{{ $comment->body }}</div></td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->lot->result_en or '---' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $comment->user->name }}
                    <td>
                        <button data-id="{{ $comment->id  }}" class="btn-link editButton"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="POST" action="{{route('comments.destroy', ['id' => $comment->id]) }}">
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn-link" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' style="color:red"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            @endforeach
```

I create a modal window to add comment to the row using JS. After i submit comment and modal is closed and i want to refresh content in `<td class="comment-body">comment</td>`

So i have a problem with refreshing div by class, i can use an id because table is looped:

```
$(function() {
            $('.editButton').click(function (e) {
                var button = $(this);

                var geturl = '/comments/' + button.data('id') + '/edit';

                var posturl = '/comments/' + button.data('id');

                $.get(geturl)
                    .done( (response) => {
                        bootbox.dialog( {
                            title : "Add comment",
                            message : response,
                            buttons : {
                                addButton : {
                                    label : 'Add comment',
                                    className : 'btn btn-primary',
                                    callback: () => {
                                        var modalForm = $('#modalForm');

                                        if ($('#commentBody').val()) {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type : 'POST',
                                                url : posturl,
                                                data : modalForm.serialize(),
                                                success : (response) => {
                                                    if (response === "ok") {
                                                        bootbox.hideAll();
                                                        $('.comment-body').toggle();


                                                    }
                                                }
                                            })
                                        }
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                },
                                closeButton : {
                                    label : 'Close',
                                    className : 'btn btn-default'
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    })
                    .fail( ( errorResponse ) => {
                        bootbox.alert('Error! Comment is not added');
                    });

            });

        });
    </script>
```

My modal view:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="#" id="modalForm" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
            <textarea name="body" id="commentBody"
                      placeholder="Add Your Comment Here." class="form-control" required>{{ $comment->body }}</textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

I tried to use `$('.comment-body').toggle();` but it is not working. How should i refresh that div after editing comment?

Comment: Could you please clarify where we can find `<td class="comment-body">comment</td>` in your HTML? I see `<td class="refresh">comment</td>` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If I got your point** .. I think its very simple

**1st**: you need to use after `var button = $(this);`

```
var comment_section = button.closest('tr').find('.comment-body');
```

**2nd**: on `ajax` success callback function

```
comment_section.text($('#commentBody').val());
```

Comment: @DmitryMalys glad to hear that .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var old_comment = $('.comment-body').text();
$('.comment-body').text(old_comment + '\n' + new_comment);
```

I don't really understand about your *refresh*. The code above is to append a new comment to old ones.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain how this work?  i paste this code but it didn't work ...

Comment: How can i define `var new_comment` ?

Comment: @DmitryMalys of coz u cant just paste it. This code only gives you the idea how to do it, since you didnt provide enough code / explain enough for us.

Comment: i updated my question. Hope it can give more full picture

Comment: @DmitryMalys Sorry for the confusion. The idea is to save old comments, and concatenate with new one to get new content. And then overwrite the whole div's text with it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the innerHTML of the element to populate it, or use empty string to clear it:

```
$('.comment-body').html("New Comment") // New contents
$('.comment-body').html("") // Clear contents
```

If you have a `.comment-body` in more than one row of your table, and you only want to "refresh" **one** of them, then you'll need to specify an id so you can pinpoint the row that contains the cell.  E.g...

```
<tr id="row1"><td class="comment-body">..comment..</td><tr>

$("#row1").find(".comment-body").html("New Comment Text")
```

NB: Instead of `.html` you may also use `.text` to prevent html code in users' comments from being injected into your page.

Comment: Empty string just removes all the comments :(

Comment: Well what do you mean exactly by " i want to refresh content in <td class="comment-body">comment</td>"?  What is the content?

Comment: after i input new comment in modal form and submit it, i want it to appear in  `<td class="comment-body">comment</td>`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately i cant use ID because the table is generated by foreach loop. :(

Comment: Is the button in the same row of the table as the comments? (You didn't actually include the comment-body in your sample HTML)  There are a number of ways to identify the corresponding row, but we need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.comment-body').('');
```

Try this or

```
$('.comment-body').html('');
```

Comment: It is just removes all the comments in that div, what i want to achieve is to input update comment in stead of old in exact that row